# xcode13 nativescript deployment_target error while building the IOS app

Tags: ios, xcode, nativescript, xcode13.3

While I'm building my Nativescript app using Xcode, I'm getting the below error. May I know what is the reason? I'm able to build the app successfully in Xcode 11 but not in 13. Thanks in advance

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build-step-metadata-generator.py", line 42, in <module>
    deployment_target = env(env("DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_ENV_NAME"))
  File "./build-step-metadata-generator.py", line 14, in env
    return os.environ[env_name]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'DEPLOYMENT_TARGET_CLANG_ENV_NAME'
Command Ld failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Comment: did you find any solution on this yet??? facing the same issue @Kranthi

Comment: Not yet @RageshPikalmunde. For now, downgraded the version to fix the issue. Please let here know if you ever find the solution. That will help others who are facing this issue.